# Get Version in Kotlin/Java code in Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, version

I have a webservice coded in kotlin and managed by gradle for the build/dependencies etc...

I want to do a simple thing: When someone call the `version` REST endpoint of my webservice, it returns the version.

Since gradle already handle the version with the `version` properties in `build.gradle`, I thought it would be easy to get this value but it seems it is not... I've been searching google for hours and everything seems so complicated.

Any idea how to handle the version the good way?

Here is what I have right now:

**build.gradle**

```
version = "1.0.0"
...
```

**StatusService.kt**

```
class StatusService : IStatusService {

    //TODO: Here I would like to get the version from the gradle 
    //file instead of maintaining 2 places for the version
    //Something like Gradle.getProperties("version") for example
    override fun getVersion() : String = "1.0.0"

}
```

I may be completely wrong about this so if you have another equivalent solution, I will accept it too! Thanks

Comment: Do you use `gradle run` or execute the resulting jar?

Comment: Why don't you simply write the version straight to the source code via gradle using `filter(ReplaceTokens...)`?

Comment: @xuesheng Never heard of this method. Feel free to add a possible answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One approach to this is to output a version file as part of your Gradle build to a location in your classpath that is accessible as a resource within your application.

For example:

You can add this to your build.gradle file which will generate a properties file containing the project version number and add it to your applications source set so that it is available in the classpath.

```
def generatedVersionDir = "${buildDir}/generated-version"

sourceSets {
    main {
        output.dir(generatedVersionDir, builtBy: 'generateVersionProperties')
    }
}

task generateVersionProperties {
    doLast {
        def propertiesFile = file "$generatedVersionDir/version.properties"
        propertiesFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
        def properties = new Properties()
        properties.setProperty("version", rootProject.version.toString())
        propertiesFile.withWriter { properties.store(it, null) }
    }
}
processResources.dependsOn generateVersionProperties
```

Then in your code you will be able to access it by reading in the properties file:

```
class StatusService : IStatusService {
    private val versionProperties = Properties()

    init {
        versionProperties.load(this.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/version.properties"))
    }

    override fun getVersion() : String = versionProperties.getProperty("version") ?: "no version"
}
```

Of course you might find it simpler and more appropriate to just output a String to the version file, and then read in the entire file as a String in your code instead of using a properties file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this!

Comment: The first section works perfectly, the file is generated in the build folder. Unfortunately, I'm not able to load it using `this.javaClass.getResourceAsStream`. Should it be generated in the `build/resources` folder instead? It always return `null` and the `load` crashes with a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Oh! Got it working! Just need to add `/` before `version.properties` in the `getResourceAsStream` function! Thanks!!!

Comment: Great, I was about to suggest that - I'll correct my answer

Comment: @JKLy, Unfortunately, I'm not able to load too it using this.javaClass.getResourceAsStream. My load crashes with a NullPointerException. This is still works? Maybe I need to start this task "generateVersionProperties" somehow?

Comment: This works fine when running the code from IntelliJ Idea, but when I generate a jar artifact, it always crashes with a null pointer exception.

Comment: @FranMarzoa you should check that the `version.properties` is in the jar artifact. If it's not, then something in your build process isn't copying it in properly.

Comment: Thanks JK Ly, I had already fixed it and that was the issue.

Answer (score 4):

It took some time to figure out how translate the accepted answer to `build.gradle.kts`, but this works:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.util.Properties

version = "your-version"

val generatedVersionDir = "$buildDir/generated-version"

sourceSets {
  main {
    kotlin {
      output.dir(generatedVersionDir)
    }
  }
}

tasks.register("generateVersionProperties") {
  doLast {
    val propertiesFile = file("$generatedVersionDir/version.properties")
    propertiesFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    val properties = Properties()
    properties.setProperty("version", "$version")
    val out = FileOutputStream(propertiesFile)
    properties.store(out, null)
  }
}

tasks.named("processResources") {
  dependsOn("generateVersionProperties")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern build.gradle.kts it is rather simpler. In the build file all you need is to add a task:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<ProcessResources>() {
    doLast {
        val propertiesFile = file("$buildDir/resources/main/version.properties")
        propertiesFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
        val properties = Properties()
        properties.setProperty("version", rootProject.version.toString())
        propertiesFile.writer().use { properties.store(it, null) }
    }
}
```

Now you have it packed and can use it the way you want, I prefer a helper like:

```kotlin
object Config : LogTag("CONF") {

    private val versionProps by lazy {
        Properties().also {
            it.load(this.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/version.properties"))
        }
    }

    val version by lazy {
        versionProps.getProperty("version") ?: "no version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider simple *Kotlin* Spring Boot example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
class DemoApplication {
    @Value("\${version}")
    private lateinit var version: String

   @GetMapping("/version")
   fun version() = version
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

Since the property could be taken from *application.properties* we need to generate that file with required version. To do so we could create a template properties file with following content:

```
version=###appVersion
```

Now lets tell Gradle to copy that template to the `resource` folder and put the version instead of placeholder

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

task preprocessProperties(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/resources/templates'
    into 'src/main/resources'
    include 'template.properties'
    rename 'template.properties', 'application.properties'
    filter(ReplaceTokens, beginToken: '###', endToken: '', tokens: [appVersion: '1.0.0'])
}

compileKotlin.dependsOn preprocessProperties
```

And, voilà, every time you compile *Kotlin* sources you will get a property file with the version you need.

Comment: I used the essence of this approach for my Java based Spring Boot application and it worked great.   In `build.gradle` I just defined a function to update the application's properties directly, then called it where it made sense for my workflow, which was building a docker image in my case.   Here's the function I used for that: ```def setVersionProperty() {
 exec {
  commandLine 'sh', '-c', "sed -i.bak \"s/^version:.*\$/version: ${project.version}/\" src/main/resources/application.yml && rm src/main/resources/application.yml.bak"
 }
}```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is present only at the compilation, not at Runtime.

For doing this, you have to generate a class at the compilation time.
With `Android` project, the file `BuildConfig.java` is generated but I don't know if it's Gradle or Android.

For generating Kotlin code, you can check [KotlinPoet](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet).